# How can I have multiple widgets per page?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm new to Ember.js, and I've spent the last couple of days looking at whether Ember.js is suitable for a project I'm working on. I don't know if widget is the right word to use here, but I don't know what else to call it.

My app needs to show multiple 'widgets' on any given page. For example, the homepage of the app might show recent news, system updates, and recent posts. On all pages there might be one or more omnipresent widgets (think of the friends list on Facebook).

Can Ember.js handle this? Everything I've read binds a URI to a route, and a route a single model (or collection of the same model type). What do I need to read up on to learn more about how to implement what I need to implement?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Ember Components](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/), you can pass them a model and they have a self container controller/view and template, they are great for creating reusable UI elements that have self contained logic.

For omnipresent things, you can look into the [Application Template](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/the-application-template/) and [Nested Routes](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/). Nested routes are great for creating hierarchy in your UI:

For example, your page header/footer would in the Application Template, you have a route "/posts" which contains a list of posts on a sidebar, and then a nested route "/post" which populates the main content area of your screen. If you access a the url /posts/1, it will show the Header/Footer (Application Template), the Posts List (Posts Template) and the content of the post with id 1 (Post Template).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'm not sure if Ember is right for you.  Ember's router is implemented like a stack.  Take the following url

```
#/clock/weather/time
```

when a user decides they don't want the `clock` widget it will need to pop all of the items off the url to remove the `clock` (destroying all the child views).

Now if the url itself doesn't represent the widgets it may be a different story.  If the widgets are based off a user setting and aren't represented by the url then it'll work perfectly fine for you.